# Модуль доставки VirtueMart 1.1.4

Tags: joomla

Плиз! Подскажите! Просмотрел все в сети, не могу найти необходимое по теме: в VirtueMart 1.1.4 при оформлении заказа не отображаются варианты доставки (тарифы, свойства товаров, диапазон индексов, пропуск "кг." выставлены!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Оказывается еще необходимо было в тарифах доставки отменить выбор своей страны (клик в списке при нажатом CTRL).